# Green's function approach in Tight-Binding

Tags: solid-state-physics, greens-functions, tight-binding

I am studying single-particle Green's functions using Economou's textbook, and am interested in using them to calculate surface states in tight-binding models. What I don't really understand is what benefit the Green's function method provides [Green](https://doi.org/10.1016/0039-6028(71)90115-4), as opposed to just using the Hamiltonian itself. [Ham](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.465096)

Answer (score 1):

One example quantity that one would like to know from a given Hamiltonian 
is the density-of-states (DOS), which is related directly to measurable quantities, e.g. conductance. Instead of diagonalizing the Hamiltonian 
to know the DOS, the trace of the imaginary part of the Green function then
gives the DOS. 
By the way, the Green function is defined through Hamiltonian. So the question is a bit confusing.